# How to convert JSON API images from an API to base64 for display on webpage?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am looking to parse the following page and extract every photo. I am looking to add a picture to the card http://api.openparliament.ca/politicians/.

I have been following this guide for reference: https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript/ However when it runs, the pictures fail to appear. What am I doing wrong?

```
(function() {
const app = document.getElementById('root');
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('class', 'container');

app.appendChild(container);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://api.openparliament.ca/politicians/?format=json', true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4) { 
        if (request.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        data.objects.forEach(politician => {
            const card = document.createElement('div');
            card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

            const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
            h1.textContent = politician.name;              

            const p1 = document.createElement('p');
            p1.textContent = `${politician.current_riding.name.en}, ${politician.current_riding.province}`
            const p2 = document.createElement('p');
            p2.textContent = politician.current_party.short_name.en

            const img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = politician.image

            container.appendChild(card);
            card.appendChild(h1);
            card.appendChild(img);                
            card.appendChild(p1);
            card.appendChild(p2);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('error');
    }
}
}   
request.send();
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `politician.image` is of the form `/media/polpics/ziad-aboultaif.jpg`.

You have to prepend the server name as well:

```
img.src = `http://api.openparliament.ca/${politician.image}`
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a rockstar! Thank you so much!

Comment: @SeanMichaelConway Any reason for unaccepting the answer?

Comment: Yes, I am new to this and I completely forgot to. My apologies!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the data returns a relative URL to the image.  You need to prefix `politician.image` with the base url.  Something like this:

```
img.src = "//api.openparliament.ca" + politician.image;
```

You will have the same issue when you try to link to the `politician.url` page as well.

Comment: I appreciate you responding so quickly. It works like a charm. Thank you!